# ssjs System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]

Tags: javascript, rest-api, json, ssjs, javascript-debugging

I have a SSJS code that i am running SFMC cloudpages. The code is to do a HTTP.GET call to a url and then parse the JSON response.when trying to write out the result of parse i receive the following error message:

System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]

when i try to write out the variable "resultString" i get the JSON response exactly as it should be. but when i try to write out the variable json_el ( the supposed parsed string ) i get the error. I also tried writing out the key values in the JSON object such as Write(json_el.SchoolList[0].SchoolName); and the error does not occur but it produces blank or just nothing. i tried replacing String() function with Stringify() but results were either blank or the same error. I have looked at other questions in the community and still can't seem to figure out what the problem is. please help me as this is urgent and i am pretty much stuck on something that should be working.

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var newsletterDE = DataExtension.Init("utility_subs_geo_appended");
var newsletterRows = newsletterDE.Rows.Retrieve();

  
// Make REST API call and get JSON response
var url_el = ('https://api.schooldigger.com/v2.0/schools?st=GA&level=Elementary&isVirtual=false&nearLatitude=33.171511&nearLongitude=-84.904805 &distanceMiles=15&page=1&perPage=1&sortBy=rank&includeUnrankedSchoolsInRankSort=false&appID=eed66488&appKey=9e64916a9410250d80f9740479c4512e');
var response_el = HTTP.Get(url_el);
var resultString = String(response_el.Content);
var json_el = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(resultString);

Write(json_el);

</script>
```

Comment: What exact attributes do you want to get from the response?

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting an error, but rather you're writing out exactly what you've asked for. Your json_el variable contains a C# [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0) and you're told that the variable contains an object. If you want to see the key value pairs stored in the Dictionary Object, Stringify it before printing:

```js
    Write(Stringify(json_el));
```

JavaScript is case sensitive, so if you want to inspect your json_el object, you'll need to pay attention to the casing of attribute names. The names of both your "schoolList" array and the "schoolName" property start with a lowercase "s", not uppercase, so to print out the name of the first school in your array, you'd need to do it, so...

```js
    Write(json_el.schoolList[0].schoolName);
```